# FindBugs RV_ABSOLUTE_VALUE_OF_RANDOM_INT warning

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm trying to do a code review for our project using FindBugs.

we have a method to generate unique id (randomly) :

```
 public static String generateUUID(int base){

    return String.valueOf(getCurrentTimeInNanos((long)base))  + 

                     String.valueOf(Math.abs(random.nextInt()));
 }
```

and findBugs indicates `RV_ABSOLUTE_VALUE_OF_RANDOM_INT` warning (RV: Bad attempt to compute absolute value of signed 32-bit random integer ) , i guess the problem is in `String.valueOf(Math.abs(random.nextInt())`.

Does anyone have an explanation for why is this and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe it is because [Math.abs can actually return negative results for integer inputs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29):

```
assertTrue( Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) < 0 );
```

It only does this for MIN_VALUE, though, because -MIN_VALUE cannot be represented. Kind of an overflow problem.

As for how to fix it:

- don't make your own UUID. Use [java.util.UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).
- cast the random number to long before calling Math.abs
- use random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) to get a number from 0 to MAX_VALUE - 1

Comment: Since there is no random.nextLong(long) method, you can use use this as a quick hack:   Math.abs( Math.max(random.nextLong(), Long.MIN_VALUE + 1)) : guarantees a result in the range 0..Long.MAX_VALUE.